# How to write htaccess rewrite rule for change link

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i'm searching for rule for change link in htaccess.

Currently the link looks like this:

```
localhost.com/forum/profile.php?id=1
```

And this is the effect I would like to achieve:

```
localhost.com/forum/profile/1
```

I added the following rules:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/forum/profile\.php\?id=([0-9]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /forum/profile/%1? [R=301,L]
```

The problem is that the page automatically redirects to the expected link, but a 404 error is returned

Comment: “Currently the link looks like this” - just to clarify, you do still need to change the actual link in the HTML source, if you haven’t already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need one more rule to map `forum/profile/123` to `forum/profile\.php?id=123`. Please clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/forum/profile\.php\?id=([0-9]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /forum/profile/%1? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^forum/profile/([0-9]+)/?$ /forum/profile.php?id=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Comment: Yes, everything works. Thank you very much! <3